# Fixing alignment for the first and the last row in a table where numbers are alighed by the decimal point

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting

I'm trying to align the first and the last row in a table, where the rest of the data is numerical and is aligned by a decimal digit. I found a hack to go around this problem, but looking for a nicer way to solve this, any help will be appreciated!

When I do the aligning of the numbers as in the code below, the labels in the last row and the numbering in the top row are not centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{table}
        \centering 
        {\footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}{r|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|c}
                \hline
                \hline
                sample \# & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 &
                $\cdots$  \\ 
                \hline
                Variance (Wavelet Coef.) &  -1.3971 & 4.5459 &  3.8660
                & 3.4566
                & 0.3292 & 0.3901 & $\cdots$   
                \\
                Skewness (Wavelet Coef.)  & 3.3191 & 8.1674&-2.6383
                & 9.5228
                & -4.4552  & -0.1428 & $\cdots$ 
                \\
                Kurtosis (Wavelet Coef.)
                & -1.3927 & -2.4586 & 1.9242
                & -4.0112
                & 4.5718 & -0.0319 & $\cdots$ \\ 
                Entropy (Wavelet Coef.) & -1.9948 &-1.4621& 0.1065
                & -3.5944
                & -0.9888 &  0.3508 & $\cdots$ 
                \\ 
                Genuine or Forged & 1 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 1 & $\cdots$ \\
                \hline
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note the numbers (titles and labels) in the first and last row are not centered)

I can try to do a very nice hack, as below, where I define the minimal column width to center the first and the last row, defining a new column type:

```
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|}
```

I manually set the column width (1cm) and tweak the number of digits before and after the decimal point (setting it to d{1.2} in the column definiiton of the table).

Is there a better way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{table}
        \centering 
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|}
        {\footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}{r|d{1.2}|d{1.2}|d{1.2}|d{1.2}|d{1.2}|d{1.2}|c}
                \hline
                \hline
                sample \# & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{1}   & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{5}   & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{6} &
                $\cdots$  \\ 
                \hline
                Variance (Wavelet Coef.) &  -1.3971 & 4.5459 &  3.8660
                & 3.4566
                & 0.3292 & 0.3901 & $\cdots$   
                \\
                Skewness (Wavelet Coef.)  & 3.3191 & 8.1674&-2.6383
                & 9.5228
                & -4.4552  & -0.1428 & $\cdots$ 
                \\
                Kurtosis (Wavelet Coef.)
                & -1.3927 & -2.4586 & 1.9242
                & -4.0112
                & 4.5718 & -0.0319 & $\cdots$ \\ 
                Entropy (Wavelet Coef.) & -1.9948 &-1.4621& 0.1065
                & -3.5944
                & -0.9888 &  0.3508 & $\cdots$ 
                \\ 
                Genuine or Forged & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{1}  & $\cdots$ \\
                \hline
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }   
    \end{table}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Note, the hack helps, the first and the last row are alighned, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A simple `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}` should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` also works to horizontally center cells in `d` type columns. In the following MWE, I have also included an alternative using `siunitx`.

In the third table, I have removed vertical lines and replaced the `\hline`commands with horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package and also slightly reduced the values of `\tabcolsep` to make sure the table fits into the textwidth.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering 
        {\footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}{r|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|d{2.4}|c}
                \hline
                \hline
                sample \# & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6} &
                $\cdots$  \\ 
                \hline
                Variance (Wavelet Coef.) &  -1.3971 & 4.5459 &  3.8660
                & 3.4566
                & 0.3292 & 0.3901 & $\cdots$   
                \\
                Skewness (Wavelet Coef.)  & 3.3191 & 8.1674&-2.6383
                & 9.5228
                & -4.4552  & -0.1428 & $\cdots$ 
                \\
                Kurtosis (Wavelet Coef.)
                & -1.3927 & -2.4586 & 1.9242
                & -4.0112
                & 4.5718 & -0.0319 & $\cdots$ \\ 
                Entropy (Wavelet Coef.) & -1.9948 &-1.4621& 0.1065
                & -3.5944
                & -0.9888 &  0.3508 & $\cdots$ 
                \\ 
                Genuine or Forged & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & $\cdots$ \\
                \hline
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}



    \begin{table}
        \centering 
        {\footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}{r|*{6}{S[table-format=2.4]}|c}
                \hline
                \hline
                sample \# & {1}  & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} &
                $\cdots$  \\ 
                \hline
                Variance (Wavelet Coef.) &  -1.3971 & 4.5459 &  3.8660
                & 3.4566
                & 0.3292 & 0.3901 & $\cdots$   
                \\
                Skewness (Wavelet Coef.)  & 3.3191 & 8.1674&-2.6383
                & 9.5228
                & -4.4552  & -0.1428 & $\cdots$ 
                \\
                Kurtosis (Wavelet Coef.)
                & -1.3927 & -2.4586 & 1.9242
                & -4.0112
                & 4.5718 & -0.0319 & $\cdots$ \\ 
                Entropy (Wavelet Coef.) & -1.9948 &-1.4621& 0.1065
                & -3.5944
                & -0.9888 &  0.3508 & $\cdots$ 
                \\ 
                Genuine or Forged & {1} & {0}  & {0}  & {0}  & {0}  & {1} & $\cdots$ \\
                \hline
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}

        \begin{table}
        \footnotesize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
        \centering 
            \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{S[table-format=-1.4]}c}
                \toprule
                sample \# & {1}  & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} &
                $\cdots$  \\ 
                \midrule
                Variance (Wavelet Coef.) &  -1.3971 & 4.5459 &  3.8660
                & 3.4566
                & 0.3292 & 0.3901 & $\cdots$   
                \\
                Skewness (Wavelet Coef.)  & 3.3191 & 8.1674&-2.6383
                & 9.5228
                & -4.4552  & -0.1428 & $\cdots$ 
                \\
                Kurtosis (Wavelet Coef.)
                & -1.3927 & -2.4586 & 1.9242
                & -4.0112
                & 4.5718 & -0.0319 & $\cdots$ \\ 
                Entropy (Wavelet Coef.) & -1.9948 &-1.4621& 0.1065
                & -3.5944
                & -0.9888 &  0.3508 & $\cdots$ 
                \\ 
                Genuine or Forged & {1} & {0}  & {0}  & {0}  & {0}  & {1} & $\cdots$ \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```